# SwitchDisplayable a la Android

Tags: java, android, java-me

i'm still porting a J2ME app to Android and now my problem is with the GUI.
For what i've seen, Android's Activities are great, but my J2ME is filled with the classic:

```
public void switchDisplayable(Alert alert, Displayable nextDisplayable) {
        Display display = getDisplay();
        if (alert == null)
            display.setCurrent(nextDisplayable);
        else 
            display.setCurrent(alert, nextDisplayable);
}
```

I just can't make every Displayable to an Activity, so i thought about replacing them with View. I tried that but it just doesn't works, the app doesn't changes the screen.

Update:

Thanks for answering, but placed al vews inside FrameLayout and still nothing. This is the core of my test code, so you can check it out:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text); // Shows "Hi"
        showDialog(); // it just shows a dialog asking if the user wants to change screen

    }
    showDialog() {
        // in OnClick()... i do the following, and here is where it fails, i tried so far:        
        TestView testv= new MarcoLoco(MFActivity.this);
    setContentView(testv);
        testv.invalidate();
    testv.requestFocus();
    testv.showMeSomething();
    }


public class TestView extends View{
    private Context context;
    TextView tv;    
    public TestView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context=context;
    }   
    public void showMeSomething() {
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tessto); // it should show "Bye"
    }
}
```

After the OnClick the "Hi" dissapears from the screen but nothing appears, no "Bye".

Why, oh, why!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any expirience with Java ME, but this might help you

Put your Views inside a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html), then you can use

```
mViewA.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mViewB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
mViewA.requestFocus();
```

to switch between diffrent views

EDIT:

Here is a short example program that toggles between 2 textviews:

```
public class test extends Activity {
    boolean showTV1 = true;

    OnClickListener ocl = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showTV1= !showTV1;
            if (showTV1){
                tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tv1.requestFocus();
            } else {
                tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tv2.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    };

    private TextView tv1, tv2;  

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01); 
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);

        tv1.setOnClickListener(ocl);
        tv2.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    }
}
```

and `main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#0f0"
        android:text="Hi" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#f00"
        android:text="Bye" android:visibility="gone"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! It doesn't work yet, i added a code snippet so you all can see it.

Comment: @Peter I added a short example program that toggles between 2 textviews

Comment: Thanks @getekha, that works great, i have the problem when i try to switch to a view that's in a different class, not in xml but a class that extends from view.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your questions, but try looking at [ViewAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html) and [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) - perhaps these can help

PS. just out of curiosity... have you tried any of automatic converters?

Comment: my problem is that if i try to swith from the "original", xml defined view, to another one say "MyView extends View" at runtime, it doesn't shows nothing at all. The first view disappears but the second one just doesn't shows.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you porting from J2ME to Android on your own, instead of using a conversion tool ?
Quicker, no need to learn and excel with Android, no need to debug and maintain 2 code bases... Give it a try at www.UpOnTek.com. Thanks.